# PLSQL Define A Cursor Dynamically

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am trying to create a procedure that accepts two table names as parameters, and then copies the rows from one table into another, one at a time. I know bulk insert and `SELECT INTO` are better ways to do this, but bulk insert isn't working because the table triggers throw mutation errors when I insert more than one row at once.

I've seen other answers that recommend using dynamic SQL, but I'm stuck on how to define the cursor that way.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TABLE_INSERT(
    donor_t IN VARCHAR2,
    empty_t IN VARCHAR2
    )
AS
    CURSOR C1 IS 
        SELECT * FROM donor_t;
BEGIN
    FOR row IN C1
    LOOP
        INSERT INTO empty_t VALUES row;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

When compiled as written above, compiler throws `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist.` When compiled with table names hard-coded in, this function inserts the rows as expected, without errors.

Comment: Basically what you are trying to do is an insert as select, why not do that instead?
Processing data row by row is very bad for performance.

Comment: One option is to look at your triggers and consider if they can be disabled for the bulk operation and re-enabled afterwards. Obviously your bulk operation will need to deal with the business logic performed by the triggers. Otherwise try the Oracle docs for examples - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/dynamic.htm#BHCGEFCA

Comment: @BriteSponge Didn't even occur to me to see if I could disable the triggers and re-enable them after insert; that solution worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

try this instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TABLE_INSERT(
donor_t IN VARCHAR2,
empty_t IN VARCHAR2
)
AS 
  V_SQL VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
    V_SQL := 'INSERT INTO ' || empty_t || ' SELECT * FROM ' ||  donor_t;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_SQL;
END;
/
```

Comment: That's a good solution for a dynamic insert statement, but it's unfortunately still causing the trigger to throw mutation errors since it's not one-at-a-time inserts.